# Isset() returning false when it should be true - Symfony PHP

Tags: php, symfony, if-statement, isset

I am a new developer working at a company on a website. I am using isset() to check if something is set within a variable that I know has a value, but it is always returning false. Here is the code:

```
$prices_with_source = $user_company->getBranchApiImplementation()->getApiClass($controller,$apiDisabled)->getProductPrices($em, $partnership, array( array('product' => $product , 'quantity' => 1) ));
$prices_with_source = is_array($prices_with_source) ? reset($prices_with_source) : $prices_with_source;

if(isset($prices_with_source['discountedPrice']) && $prices_with_source['discountedPrice'] > 0) {
    $price = $prices_with_source['discountedPrice'];
}

if(isset($prices_with_source['suggestedPrice'])) {
    $price = $prices_with_source['suggestedPrice'];
}
```

It is supposed to enter the if statements because I know that the $price_with_sources has values. I dont know why it is not working. I used var_dump to check the value of the $prices_with_sources before the if statements and this is the output:

```
array(1) {
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["discountedPrice"]=> string(4) "5.99"
        ["suggestedPrice"]=> string(4) "5.99"
        ["source"]=> int(0)
    }
}
```

If anyone has any helpful information it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `isset($prices_with_source[1]['discountedPrice'])`.... it's a nested array

Comment: You have a nested array there.

Comment: Index is not `'discountedPrice'`

Comment: You can always use `$row = current($prices_with_source);` if you know you only ever have a single item in the collection

Comment: @Torchify, there is two if condition.

Comment: Ah ok I see what the problem was, Konok gave me updated code as well. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Thanks for the answers its all cleared up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Accessing a two dimension array in php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp)

**updated if block:**

```
if(isset($prices_with_source[1]['discountedPrice']) && $prices_with_source[1]['discountedPrice'] > 0) {
    $price = $prices_with_source[1]['discountedPrice'];
}

if(isset($prices_with_source[1]['suggestedPrice'])) {
    $price = $prices_with_source[1]['suggestedPrice'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem. I now see what the error was!